# How to make a property field shows up in the VS property grid, not custom property grid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I made a custom control derived from `Panel`, which has some properties in it, say

```
public int Amount {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
```

How do I make it appear in the property grid of the Visual Studio, not the `PropertyGrid` control I dragged in?

Everything I could find online is talking about how to add properties to `PropertyGrid` "control", which is not what I want.

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me how to do it?

Much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Public properties of custom WinForms controls will automatically show up in the VS Properties window; rebuild your solution/restart VS if it's not showing up.

Comment: See this link if you want the property to show up in a specific section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/tk67c2t8(v=vs.120)

Comment: @CoolBots I tried both of them, but it still didn't show up! Could it be some kind of setup I had missed or the version problem? I'm using 2019.

Comment: Do you see the property if you change from categorized to alphabetical view? If so, you need to apply an attribute to it for categorized view to know where to place it. See the link in my prior comment.

Comment: @CoolBots I had tried both of them, but nothing showed up. Could it be because I had derived it from `Panel`?

Comment: If it's a UserControl, remove it from the Form and drop a fresh instance from the ToolBox, after you have rebuilt the UC. Decorate with `[Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]`

Comment: No, deriving from `Panel` is fine... Is this a Framework or Core project?

Comment: @CoolBots I got it! Thanks! Could you please be so kind and post it as an answer so I could accept it? Much appreciated!

Comment: I think it was actually @Jimi that solved it for you. If you'd like, go ahead and post an answer Q&A style, it might help others as well. I'm glad you got it resolved.

Comment: @CoolBots Whoops! Sorry! But could you please be so kind and tell me what's "Post an answer Q&A style"? Much appreciated!

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.

Comment: @CoolBots OK, thanks! But I would still like to give Jimi a chance to post it, because, after all, it's him who solved my problem, not myself!

Comment: You can post an answer yourself, or @CoolBots ca do it, it's fine, I like team efforts :) -- Possibly add a description of what those attribute are for. The reason behind the removing-adding back UCs (and Custom-Controls, sometimes) - when something meaningful has changed - is more complex, but the fact itself is enough, I think.

Comment: @Jimi OK, thanks! I'll try my best to answer it, but please do edit it by all means if I had said anything wrong! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Jimi, custom controls need to be "precompiled" before their properties would show up in the property grid, so remove every custom controls first, rebuild the project, then drag in the custom control will make everything shows up nicely.

But I also find another solution while trying out @Jimi's method, which is:

After you add a new property to the custom control, manually add the default value to the designer's page, such as `Form1.Designer.cs`, eg.

```
CustomControl.Number = 0;
```

Then it will show up in the property grid.

I guess the VS "DID" tries to show it in the property grid, but since that property is not instantiated yet, VS couldn't know what the heck is it and ends up either throwing an error or just simply ignoring it altogether!

That's why precompile it or manually adds the default value would work.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.